# Angular 2+ Add or Remove a Class of an element that belongs to another component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using Angular 4 on an application where I have 2 components ... app.component and other.component

On **app.component.html** I have a div with a class called **myClass** ...

```
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

On `other.component.ts` I currently have:

```
ngOnInit() {

 jQuery('.myClass').removeClass();
 jQuery('.myClass').addClass('someClassName');

}
```

I want to do this the angular way instead of using jQuery.

My question is...How do I do this same thing with Angular 2+ ?

Comment: First things first : how are these components related ? is OtherComponent a child of AppComponent, or is it on another route ?

Comment: It's on another route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `OtherComponent` is on another route than `AppComponent`, then you could use a service to do that :

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="myClass" #concernedDiv></div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('concernedDiv') concernedDiv: ElementRef;

constructor(private myService; MyService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.onOtherInit.subscribe(event => {
    this.concernedDiv.className = this.concernedDiv.replace('myClass', '').trim();
  });
}
```

**my-service.service.ts**

```
private sub: Subject<any> = new Subject();
public onOtherInit: Observable<any> = this.sub.asObservable();

emitEvent() { this.sub.next(/* anything you want */); }
```

**other.component.ts**

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
ngOnInit() { this.myService.emitEvent(); }
```

Comment: Seems like a lot of work for doing something that you can do with jQuery with 1 line of code :o/

Comment: Well, Angular isn't made to add or remove classes at first, and this is probably one of the many solutions, but it's the one I use !

Comment: @pedromartinez If this single line has a smell (and it has), it is worth it. A lot of current 'best' OOP practices may seem overengineered but pay off in the large scale.

Answer (score 0):

By using `ngClass` you can use statements to add / remove a class

In your component:

```
yourBooleanValue: boolean;

ngOnInit() {
    this.yourBooleanValue = true;
}
```

In html:

```
<div [ngClass]="{ 'someClassName': yourBooleanValue }"></div>
```

Comment: Can someClassName be a variable defined on other.component.ts ?

Comment: You could achieve this by using two-way binding. Throughtram has a good article about this: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html in your case trichetriche is the way to go.